# Python Playsound not playing any sound when compiled into an .exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-playsound

I'm trying to create a digital soundboard that can play object-defined sounds using tkinter and the playsound module. When I'm testing it via VS code, it works without any problems. But after I compile it into an exe, the app works but there's no sound playing.

I tried changing my compilation mode from '--onefile' to '--onedir' in pyinstaller but it didn't work. I also place the sound files into the folder directory of the executable file, but to no avail.
Could there be something wrong with my code?

my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from playsound import playsound

win = Tk()
win.geometry('500x500')
win.maxsize(500,500)
win.title('Alarm Button')

def alarm():
    playsound(r'Announcement.mp3')

btn_image = PhotoImage(file='BUTTON.png')
comp_logo = PhotoImage(file='aaaa.png')
Logo = Label(win, image = comp_logo).place(x=390, y=470)

Press_me = Button(win, image=btn_image, command=alarm, borderwidth = 0)
Press_me.place(x=45, y=15)

def handler(e):
    alarm()

win.bind('<Return>', handler)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `alarm` function is called when compiled into an exe? If the function is called then the problem isn't in `tkinter`. If so, please remove the `tkinter` tag from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and it still works, maybe it's because of pyinstaller? Or you can try using auto-py-to-exe since it works for me and also easier to use: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Make sure that you use playsound 1.2.2 because it's more stable than the 1.3.0 version. You can do it by using:

```
pip uninstall playsound
```

Then:

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Also I see that you import tkinter 2 times? You should delete

```
import tkinter
```